# Dapper - How to return record as Custom object type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, orm, dapper

I am trying to run a query  using Dapper and map data to a custom class object Emp.

```
public class Emp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My dapper execution code:

```
    string connectionString = @"Server = myserver; userid = test; password = test; database = testdb; port = 3306; Convert Zero Datetime=True";

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM EMP where empno = 1010;
        List<Emp> empList = connection.Query<Emp>(sql: sql).ToList();
    }
```

The above code is working fine.
I tried  the following,

```
    Emp emp = (Emp)connection.Query<Emp>(sql:sql);
```

Error: Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Genetic List[Emp] to type Emp

I can get the  record as below and its working.

```
    Emp emp1 = empList[0];
```

Is there anyway I can get the query return type as Emp?

Comment: The `Query<T>` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`. Just call `.FirstOrDefault()` on that and you will get wither a `T` or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method Query returns a list of records (rows).
To get only one result you need to use `QuerySingle` or `QuerySingleOrDefault`

```
Emp emp = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Emp>(query);
```